# When there is an "on" after touch?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Is it correct that I say"I touch on the book" or just "I touch the book" Sometimes I come across "touch on" in some abstract meaning, what is the difference?

Comment: If you're talking about *literally* touching a book (with your hands), then say *I touch the book*. If you're talking about *metaphorically* touching a book (addressing an idea in it), then say *I touch **on** the book*.

Answer (score 1):

touch on (something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/touch+on) is an idiom

> To discuss or deal with some topic informally or in passing.

As in:

*We'll touch on that matter later in the meeting.*

to touch  v.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/touch) A basic definition is

> To cause or permit a part of the body, especially the hand or fingers,
>   to come in contact with so as to feel

Comment: Thank you very much! So usually, it is better to say"I  touch a book" right？

Comment: correct ///////